# I cannot get the value of a table view cell in cocoa touch

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uitableview

I am trying to get the value of a cell in a table view but it won't let me.  If someone could help that would be great.

```
int numberOfChecks = -1;
numberOfChecks = numberOfChecks +1;

    if ([objectsForTable count]-1 >= numberOfChecks) {


        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:numberOfChecks];

        NSString *cellTitle = cell.textLabel.text;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cellForRowAtIndexPath: method is not provided by UITableView, that method is provided by the [UITableViewDataSource delegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:).  You should have set the dataSource property in the table to point to your delegate for this since you have to provide the data.   Assuming you did that, you could use the table's dataSource property to call your own data source:

```
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex: ... ];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView.dataSource tableView:self.tableView
                                       cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
```